# editing the iteration value in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

**Situation**

I'm trying to design a simple remove method that deletes an object if the incoming ID parameter matches an ID on record:

For instance, if a Race had an ID "123" then it would find the race that had the ID "123" and set it to null, thus removing it.

I've looked at a few methods online and yeah, it seems to be a recurring problem with foreach specifically, but I'd really like to do it this way if possible.

```
    public void removeRace(string RaceID)
            {

                foreach (BaseRace br in races)
                {
                    //if the ID entered into this method as a parameter matches an ID on record.
                if (RaceID == br.raceID)
                {
                    //set the current ID to null, thus deleting the record.
                    //br = null;

                }
            }
        }
```

**Problem**

My code, specifically `br = null;` doesn't work, since the foreach loop won't let me edit the iterator.

how can I solve this issue in another way?

Comment: What's the type of `races`?

Comment: races is a list of BaseRaces

Comment: Please list other methods you tried and reasons why it did not work. (I assume you've searched for something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+remove+item+list+foreach to get other known approaches).

Comment: Your concept of variables and foreach loops is incorrect. On each iteration, the loop control variable will get a copy of a reference from the list. Even if you could change the loop control variable's value, that wouldn't do anything to the referenced object or the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` already provides method to do that:

```
public void removeRace(string RaceID)
{
    races.RemoveAll(br => RaceID == br.raceID);
}
```

If you really don't want to use it you'd have to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`.

Comment: could you give me an example of a for? I think i'll use the first suggestion since it's cleaner code.

but an example would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it fairly simple with Linq.

```
var filter = races.Where(d => d.Id != value).ToList();
```

That would account for a single value, which it would remove. You could also do a projection, with a `SelectMany` and `Where` culmination that would also filter. Would need some more context.

This approach may not be ideal, Marcin's approach may be more ideal.  Need more context though.

Comment: what is Linq? sorry i'm relatively new to programming, people keep mentioning it.